# How to set Mockito rules at one place (super class) for all sub class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have recently started working with `@Mockito` annotation at Junit Tests.

the reason i started using `@Mockito` is because using `@Autowired` for all the service class took very long.

i have more than 50 test that using the same class for exmple: `userService`

i would like to have this at my super class

```
@Mock
    private UserService userService;
```

and to set Mocking for all the sub class , all sub class have diffrent method and multiple `@Test`

Normally what i do is adding this line in the `@Test` method :

```
 Mockito.when(userService.isValid()).thenReturn(true));
```

How could i set this Mocking at one place (in super class) and all sub class could know using this Mock ?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a class field visible to child classes?? The `@RunWith(MokcitoJunitRunner.class)` on the super class and `@Mock protected UserService userService` on the field will work

Comment: How can all the sub class know this behavior 
 Mockito.when(userService.isValid()).thenReturn(true));

Comment: why not to create a abstract test class that has setup method call "Mockito.when(userService.isValid()).thenReturn(true));"

Comment: @kuhajeyan do i need to use special annotation for setup (Init method) ?

Comment: yes. https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-1-basic-usage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by using this annotation

```
@Before – Run before @Test
```

and that where i set the rules `Mockito.when(userService.isValid()).thenReturn(true));`